# How to load a .framework file with a NativeScript Plugin

Tags: ios, nativescript

I hear from the team frameworks are better than cocoapods... and I have a framework for a component, but I'm a tad clueless how to load it and can't find any docs (am I just missing them?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your `.framework` files in your plugins `platforms/ios` folder.

You can take a look at https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins#directory-structure for more details.